Strategy to come up with $N$ for proofs of the infinitude of primes in particular congruence classes
To prove the infinitude of primes $p$ of the form $p \equiv a \mod b$ for particular $a, b$ can be done by assuming there are finitely many such primes $p_1, \dots, p_k$, defining a number $N$ which is written as some polynomial in $p_1 \dots p_k$, showing that there must be a prime factor $p \mid N$ with $p \neq p_1, \dots, p_k$, but $p \equiv a \mod b$.
For example, consider $N = (2p_1 \dots p_k)^2+1$ to show there are infinitely many prime numbers of the form $4k+1$ (see this post), or $N = (p_1 \dots p_k)^2-2$ to show there are infinitely many prime numbers of the form $8k+7$ (see this post).
Given some arbitrary congruence class $p \equiv a \mod b$ is there an algorithm/method to come up with what our choice of $N$ should be to proceed with in a proof.
Of course, there is Dirichlet's theorem establishing the result in all congruence classes where infinitely many primes exist, but I am not concerned about that in this question. I am wondering if there is some strategy for coming up with $N$ for these elementary proofs in particular cases.

It is known for which $N$ you can do such a proof in the sense of Euclid - see this post: Murty gave an argument that an elementary Euclid-style proof is impossible when $a^{2} \not\equiv 1 \pmod{q}$, while
Schur proved that if $a^{2} \equiv 1 \pmod{q}$, then there is an elementary Euclid-style argument that there are infinitely many primes $p \equiv a \pmod{q}$.
